# How to get the latest last 2 inserted records from the table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
    CREATE TABLE `testskm`(
                `mem_id`      NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
                 `mem_sal`     NUMBER(5) NOT NULL);

insert into `testskm` values (1,100);
insert into `testskm` values (1,200);
insert into `testskm` values (2,350);
insert into testskm values (2,150);
insert into testskm values (3,12);
insert into testskm values (1,300);
insert into testskm values (2,50);
insert into testskm values (3,13);
insert into testskm values (3,14);
insert into testskm values (3,15);
```

i have insert statements  for `mem_id` 1,2, & 3. I want to get the last 2 inserted records in the table for all `mem_id`.

I have the tried the below code , but its giving me only records based on the `mem_sal` as i used the order by..

```
select * from(
select
  mem_id, mem_sal, 
  --max(sysdate) over (partition by mem_id) latest,
  rank() over( partition BY mem_id order by mem_sal ) RISK_ORDER
  from testskm)
  where RISK_ORDER <= 2
```

i want output of these inserted records:

```
insert into `testskm` values (1,200);
insert into `testskm` values (1,300);
insert into `testskm` values (2,150);
insert into `testskm` values (2,50);
insert into `testskm` values (3,14);
insert into `testskm` values (3,15);
```

Comment: You _can't_ really answer your question, because there is no column which keeps track of which record were inserted first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please let me know, how could i achieve the output result? do i need to change my table structure with any date column or sequence column ?. Kindly reply

Comment: Add a date/timestamp column which keeps track of when each salary record gets inserted.

Comment: using oralce 11g @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Hi Tim, i have added the bewlo column and modified the insert statement for the same ... no i am getting the expected result.

         
'alter table testskm modify insert_date date'

Comment: @Hassan: that syntax (the dreaded backticks) is invalid for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last two rows" unless a column specifies the ordering.  Your table has no such column.

You can define one.  In MySQL, this looks like:

```
create table `testskm` (
    testskm_id int auto_increment primary key,
    `mem_id`  int NOT NULL,
    `mem_sal` int NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select ts.*
from (select ts.*, row_number() over (partition by mem_id order by testskm_id desc) as seqnum
      from testskm ts
     ) ts
where seqnum <= 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59d0528de46eb47ae4b08aedcfdbad13) is a db<>fiddle.